# How to use python language server for vscode in specific path?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, archlinux, python-language-server

I'm using ArchLinux and want to use [Python Language Server](https://github.com/microsoft/python-language-server) with `vscode` to write python codes.

As I search in [aur](http://aur.archlinux.org), I found [microsoft-python-language-server](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/microsoft-python-language-server) which download and build the language server with `dotnet`.
The package gives me an executable file at `/usr/bin/mspyls`.

However, when I open `vscode`, it still downloads a new language server automatically for me at 
`.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2019.5.17059/languageServer.0.2.86/Microsoft.Python.LanguageServer`.
And there are not any config for me to specify the path to language server.

Are there any possible solution to use my own mspyls but not the one vscode downloaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the Python extension for VS Code doesn't allow you to choose your own copy of the language server to use due to compatibility requirements (e.g. changes in the LSP, other extensions like IntelliCode that need to plug into the language server, etc.).

Comment: Thank you. I have to bear the low speed of downloading the LSP.